# Can git operate in "silent mode"?

Tags: git

Is it possible to execute any git command in "silent" mode? For instance, can i say "`git push origin`" and see nothing displayed on the screen?

I suppose i can redirect IO to `/dev/null` (works fine), but .. does git allow something like this naturally?

Below is a quick script that does automatic EOD commit, used when i need to catch the train and don't want to leave code on my local computer

```
  1 clear
  2
  3 cd
  4 cd repo/active
  5
  6 for i in *
  7 do
  8   cd $i
  9   echo "Pushing " $i
 10   git add . -A >> /dev/null 
 11   git commit -a -m "EOD automatic commit" >> /dev/null 
 12   git push origin >> /dev/null 
 13   echo
 14   cd ..
 15 done
```

Please let me know.

Comment: Unrelated: rather than wrapping cmds in cd $i, cd .., you can do: for i in *; do ( cd $i; ...; ); done and run the cd in a subshell.  This is less fragile.

Comment: I wonder what Linus had in mind when he developed git, because it's clearly breaking one of the basic UNIX rule that says silence is golden. What was not answered here is if it's possible to put some setting in git's config to make it a good UNIX citizen once and for all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Redirecting output to /dev/null seems like a natural way of doing it to me. Although I have in the past defined a quiet_git shell function like this for use in cron jobs:

```
quiet_git() {
    stdout=$(tempfile)
    stderr=$(tempfile)

    if ! git "$@" </dev/null >$stdout 2>$stderr; then
        cat $stderr >&2
        rm -f $stdout $stderr
        exit 1
    fi

    rm -f $stdout $stderr
}
```

This will suppress stdout and stderr, unless the git command fails. It's not pretty; in fact the stdout file is ignored and it should just redirect that to /dev/null. Works, though. And then you can just do "quiet_git push" etc. later on in the script.

Answer (score 334):

You can use `--quiet` or `-q`, which can also be used for other Git commands:

```
git commit --quiet
git push --quiet
```

Comment: I can't seem to silence git commit this way. It ignores either flag.

Comment: What version are you using that has this flag available? I've updated to 1.9.1 (latest) and this flag is not present.

Comment: You need to add it after the command.  `git pull -q` or `git push origin master --quiet`.  I'm on git 1.8.x

Comment: @Mendhak, doesn't work (at least it's not silent).  E.g. `git pull -q origin master > /dev/null` yields "Total 4 (delta 3), reused 4 (delta 3)".  That's with git 2.0.1.

Comment: Even when using --queit (or -q), it still prints some output.
For example, when using 
git checkout -q (branch_name), if it is the first time the branch is being checked out, it will print a message saying the new branch has been setup. Is there someway (some flag) using which all such output can be silenced ?

Comment: If you actually want **NO** output, use `git command >/dev/null 2>&1`.  This redirects both stdout and stderr to /dev/null.  The `--quiet` options are for generating succinct output, not for suppressing output entirely @Ankur

Comment: In fact, some of the Git subcommands do not accept this flag. Eg `git add`

Comment: `git push --quiet` also outputs commit hook output from the remote.

Comment: Do I need `2>&1` afterwards?

Answer (score 29):

Using `&> /dev/null` at the end gives you a completely silent git command output.

```
git fetch origin master &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Only in csh, most recommend doing shell scripting using bourne shells.

Comment: @hd1 no, `&>` is a bash IO redirect operator. Look at 3.6 here  http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: @HansKrisian yes, bash brought interactive features from csh and the scripting from sh together. Quoting from the same howto: "Bash is an sh-compatible shell that incorporates useful features from the Korn shell (ksh) and C shell (csh)".

Comment: The purpose is to remove informational messages, but still display errors. I haven't studied how well-behaved is git concerning what goes to stdout and what goes to stderr, but redirecting both smells like a very bad idea.

Answer (score 10):

Note that even *with* `--quiet`, a `git fetch` (which triggers a `git gc`) would generate some output.
That is because of the [`git gc`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) part of the [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Not anymore, starting git 2.1.1 (Sept 2014): see [commit 6fceed3bea59d747c160972c67663e8b8c281229](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fceed3bea59d747c160972c67663e8b8c281229) from  [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds)

### fetch: silence `git-gc` if `--quiet` is given

[`builtin/fetch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6fceed3bea59d747c160972c67663e8b8c281229/builtin/fetch.c#L1199-L1201):

```
argv_array_pushl(&argv_gc_auto, "gc", "--auto", NULL);
if (verbosity < 0)
argv_array_push(&argv_gc_auto, "--quiet");
run_command_v_opt(argv_gc_auto.argv, RUN_GIT_CMD);
```