# What's the difference between git -q pull and git pull?

Tags: git, github

I've seen this on a question about a git cronjob where `git -q pull origin master` was being used. But I simply can't find anything on what the `-q`parameter does?
What difference is there in using, for example: `git pull origin master` vs `git -q pull origin master`?

Also does this parameter have some effect on the `git push` command?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/ is an online version of the Git manual pages; you’ll be able to find every option there. [This one is the first listed for `git pull`.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html#_options)

Comment: I had done a search on google and here at SO and didn't find any...

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot: see also `git help pull`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: `git -q pull` wouldn't work.

The [git command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git) itself has no `-q` parameters.

[`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) does:

```
git pull -q origin master
```

Even though it isn't [fully quiet](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-pull-quiet-is-not-quiet-td7563533.html):

> It is actually only "quiet" if no problems are found
>
> If unmerged error occurs, output is seen on BOTH stdout and stderr.

See also "[Can git operate in “silent mode”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8943693/6309)"

Comment: Note: `man git` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git) is different from man `git pull` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Answer (score 3):

It's simply a flag for "quiet", as stated in the [official documentation for `git pull`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html#_options)

> ```
> -q
> --quiet
> ```
>
> This is passed to both underlying git fetch to squelch reporting of during transfer, and underlying git-merge to squelch output during merging.

You can also find this information in your terminal (assuming that you're using a *nix operating system) with `man git-pull`.

Push has this option too.