# git add . --quiet: quiet option not available

Tags: git, unix, io

I've just untargzipped some code and I want to add a whole bunch of files
at once to the repository and commit. Unfortunately git add doesn't have
a `--quiet` flag and all that I/O to print every single file from the tarball
is slowing things down. How can I speed this operation up (by silencing
output from `git add`?).

What I would like to do is:

```
git add . --quiet
```

Since this flag does not exist I've tried redirecting standard error:

```
git add . 2&> /dev/null
```

Unfortunately git strangely returns without adding any files when I do this.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You could always just do `git add . > /dev/null`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8944284/6309 can help too.

Comment: Thank you for posting the link to the related post which contains a lot of useful information. However I'm not sure what is going wrong. I'm using Git compiled with its version number set to 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0 inside Aptana Studio 3 build 3.6.0.201407100658. In this environment when I direct stdout and stderr to /dev/null the output is still printed, just as though I didn't redirect. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

How about simply:

```
git add . 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

You can also do things like logging the warnings/errors to one file and the output to another with:

```
git add . 1>git.log 2>git.err
```