# How to perform a non-interactive git pull?

Tags: git

I'm trying to write an automated build script, and one step pulls and merges the upstream master into the current branch. To do this, I'm running:

```
git pull origin master
```

However, if it finds any changes, it launches a terminal editor and prompts me to enter a merge comment. Why is a pull action trying to merge, and how do I disable this so it doesn't block the automated script?

If it can automatically merge, then it should complete with with no error code and no user prompts. Only if there's a conflict, should it return an error code.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943693/can-git-operate-in-silent-mode/33192221

Answer (score 19):

Probably you've configured your machine to execute a merge instead of a rebase while doing a pull.

Try this instead:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

It shall not request for your input if there's not a conflict.

Other option if you actually want the pull executed by merge instead of rebase is to resign to edit the commit message with something like this:

```
git pull --no-edit origin master
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for too long! it's a pain in the ass to always close that vim stuff.