# How to set --quiet flag by default in git?

Tags: linux, git, command-line, configuration

The git output is very verbose for me.
How can I set --quiet flag by default to all commands in git?

**EDIT:**
I have to use this -q mode in git jenkins plugin. I can't use alias, redirect to dev/null.

Comment: Only by redirecting the output, please review this question: [can-git-operate-in-silent-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943693/can-git-operate-in-silent-mode)

Comment: I wonder what Linus had in mind when he developed git, because it's clearly breaking one of the basic UNIX rule that says silence is golden. It's very disappointing that there's no way to put some setting in git's config to make it a good UNIX citizen once and for all.

Comment: Furthermore, what users would probably prefer is not a totally silent mode, but a mode that removes the useless clutter about low-level technical details (e.g., "Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)"), and still keep relevant information about state changes (e.g. "0f78294..16fbd38  master -> master").

Comment: Finally, please someone remove that wrong duplicate tag that  phd, Owen Pauling, Ctx, matino and Console put without probably reading or understanding the matter at hand. It's clearly not a duplicate, only related.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the quiet flag for all your commands in the gitconfig. As @torek [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706833/how-to-set-quiet-flag-by-default-in-git/46707906#comment80376534_46707906), there is no way to set built-in commands as aliases. So set up your aliases as they are the more convenient to you.

```
[alias]
    commitq=commit --quiet
    commit-quiet=commit --quiet
    pushq=push --quiet
    st=status -s
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Git refuses to allow an alias for a built in command. You can usually set this sort of thing up in your shell, but not in the `[alias]` section of a `.gitconfig`.

Comment: Well, you're right, I totally forgot about this kind of limitation in alias section. I'll edit my answer for the reader convenience.

Comment: You're right. But I have to use this --quiet mode with git plugin on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

No, there does not appear to be a 'git config' setting to set all commands to run in quiet mode - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

If there is a set of git commands you use frequently, perhaps add aliases in your shell config to run those with `-q` option?