# Can git push operate in “silent mode” *just* for "Everything up-to-date"?

Tags: git

I'm running a cron job every 5min, and at the end it includes `git push`

I'm looking for a way to log everything except for "Everything up-to-date" (aka no work done)

Is there a way to silence just the 'no work done' commands?

*Related to '[Can git operate in "silent mode"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943693/can-git-operate-in-silent-mode)'*

Answer (score 1):

```
git push |& grep -v "Everything up-do-date" > OUTPUT.txt
```

Comment: This is the way I ended up putting in after posting this, but it feels cludgy. I will mark it as the answer but under protest if there is no more elegant way to do it.

Comment: The only built in quiet function suppresses all normal output. `git push -q`